# How can you use an entity-relationship diagram to document business processes?

Tags: erd, database-diagrams

Past exam question: How can you use an entity relationship diagram to document business processes?

As far as I know, I would use an entity-relationship diagram (ERD) to document the relationships between data entities when designing a database. I can't see how ERD's can be used for business processes as flow charts are more suited for this. I would really appreciate if someone could give an example of how this is done.

All the examples I've found online relating to ERD's are for databases and not business processes.

Comment: Well, it's always possible that the prof actually wanted the answer "You can't". But, that seems relatively unlikely. And, the question does say "can", not "should", so it doesn't have to be the best way to document things.